# How can I have an array of values in a single FormControl?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am developing a file-upload component where is possible to upload from 1 to multiple files at the same time.

When the user clicks 'choose...' he can select one or more files to upload. Then, he gets a preview of the files chosen for the upload.

My issue is about the filename stored into the control, which contains just one string independently on how many files the user chose to upload. The filename, along other file informations, are the sent to the app-table. So what can I do to save every filename into one control?

Here is my code:

**Template**

```
<div *ngIf="config">

<section id="actionBar">
    <div>
        <label class="file-upload">
            <input
                type="file"
                multiple
                accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg"
                [formControl]="upload"
                (change)="previewFile($event); build($event)
            "
            />
            Choose...
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <!--upload btn-->
        <app-button-group
            [items]="config.buttons"
            [item]="{
                        icon: fileExtention,
                        image: previewImg,
                        name: fileName,
                        dimensions: sizeUnit
                    }"
        >
        </app-button-group>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="preview">
    <div>
        <h3>Preview</h3>
    </div>
    // single file
    <ng-container *ngIf="previewImg">
        <div>
            <h4>{{fileName}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img [src]="previewImg" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
        </div>
    </ng-container>
    // multiple files
    <ng-container *ngIf="previewMultipleImg">
        <div>
            <h4>{{fileName}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div *ngFor="let i of previewMultipleImg">
            <img [src]="i" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</section>
<app-table
    [tableSchema]="config.tableSchema"
    [dataSource]="config.dataSource"
>
</app-table>
```

**Controller**

```
export class UploadComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() config;
@Input() schema
@Input() dataSource
upload = new FormControl('');
size: number = 0;
unit: string = "";
fileExtention: string;
fileName: string;
sizeUnit: string = `${this.size}+${this.unit}`;
icon: any;
previewImg;
previewMultipleImg;
fileList = []
multi = []

constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {}

build(event) {
    this.formatFileName();
    this.getExtention(this.fileName)
    this.getSize(event)
    this.previewFile(event)
}

formatFileName() {
    console.log(this.upload.value);
    let filename = this.upload.value.replace(/^.*\\/, "");
    return this.fileName = filename;
}

getExtention(filename) {
    this.fileExtention = filename.split(/\.(?=[^\.]+$)/).slice(-1).pop().toString();
    return this.fileExtention
}

getSize(event) {
    const size = event.srcElement.files[0].size;
    if (size < 1000) {
        this.size = size;
        this.unit = "bytes";
    } else if (size < 1000 * 1000) {
        this.size = size / 1000;
        this.unit = "kb";
    } else if (size < 1000 * 1000 * 1000) {
        this.size = size / 1000 / 1000;
        this.unit = "mb";
    } else {
        this.size = size / 1000 / 1000 / 1000;
        this.unit = "gb";
    }
    return this.sizeUnit = `${this.size}${this.unit}`
}

previewFile(event) {
    let files = event.target.files;
    if (files.length === 1) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        const single = new Promise((res, rej) => {
            res()
        })
        single.then(res => {
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
            reader.onload = () => {
                return this.previewImg = reader.result
            }
        })
        single.catch(err => console.log(err))
    } else if (files.length > 1) {
        let x = []
        const multi = new Promise((res, rej) => {
            res(
                Object.values(files).map(e => {
                    let reader = new FileReader();
                    // @ts-ignore
                    reader.readAsDataURL(e)
                    reader.onload = () => {
                        x.push(reader.result)
                    }
                    return x
                })
            )
        });
        multi.then(res => {
            this.previewMultipleImg = res[0]
            console.log(  this.previewMultipleImg);
            return this.previewMultipleImg
        })
        multi.catch( rej => console.log(rej))
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for FormArray have a look at [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2)

Comment: I read about that but the fact that makes me doubt that it is the right solution to my problem is that FormArray tracks the value and state of a list of FormControls. In my component I just have one control that handles the files, and I think I do not need to add multiple controls. Honestly I am confused about the topic as I used FormArray only for checkboxes and select/options components

Comment: Yes you don't need FormArray because your value will be stored in `FileList` format.

Comment: Have a look at this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList

Comment: @SheikAlthaf you are totally right; I completely forgot about Filelist. Nice tip, thank you!